# Request and basic profiling information for Flask

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, logging, flask

Most web frameworks let you know the amount of time that it took to process a certain page request.  I'm starting to work with Flask framework now and am very much in need of this information but can't find any good way of getting it.  Using the werkzeug Midleware profiler is an option, but it is very verbose and provides too much information, I would ideally want to see in the basic log output "request info - 0.2s" or whatever the time is.  Is there a way of doing this?  Also, is there anyway of doing this same thing with SQLite?  I.e., getting a count of the number of sqlite calls and their times for a specific request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a look at [`flask-debugtoolbar`](https://github.com/mvantellingen/flask-debugtoolbar), it's basically the same as the `django-debug-toolbar` (if you ever used it) ported to `Flask`.

Comment: That's great during development, what about production?

Comment: @PanosJee `flask-debugtoolbar` uses the [`profile`](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) library under the hood, so you'd have to do by hand what `flask-debugtoolbar` does for you. I suggest you have a look at the source code for [`flask_debugtoolbar.DebugToolbarExtension`](https://github.com/mgood/flask-debugtoolbar/blob/master/flask_debugtoolbar/__init__.py#L37) and [`flask_debugtoolbar.panels.profiler.ProfilerDebugPanel`](https://github.com/mgood/flask-debugtoolbar/blob/master/flask_debugtoolbar/panels/profiler.py#L15) too see how this is achieved.